# The bash script and ampersand

Tags: bash, alias, openvpn

i've got problem - here is my bash script:

```
#!bin/bash

cd /home/user/Downloads

openvpn --config VPN.conf &

ssh login@ip
```

when I execute this (it is alias in .bashrc 
(alias xcommand='. /home/user/Desktop/start_openvpn.sh'), my program frozen after 2 line, and i can't do nothing about it.
But if I'm doing it sequentially, it is working (i must push enter after 2 commands - openvpn)

How to fix that?

Thanx,
Samantha.

Comment: It sounds like `openvpn` is reading from `stdin`, but not using the data. You might try `openvpn --config VPN.conf </dev/null &`

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running OpenVPN in verbose mode (1 is default, 9 is max) may give you more insight into what's going on:

```
openvpn --verb 9 --config VPN.conf
```